# Create an executable jar for Swing app

Tags: java, swing, jar, classnotfoundexception, executable-jar

I have created a Java application called `App.java`. It uses GSON. Hence I created a jar `gson.jar` and then created a manifest file (`manifest.mf`) with the following content.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: test.jar gson.jar
Main-Class: App
```

I then created the test.jar using the following command:

```
jar cfm test.jar manifest.mf *
```

Edit: `jar cfm test.jar manifest.mf *` **is producing the jar** but nowhere to be seen on the disk.

and run it using

```
java -jar test.jar
```

The application throws `ClassNotFoundException` for `ExitListener`. When the code that uses `ExitListner` is removed, it runs normal as it were run using java App. What am I missing?

Comment: Where does ExitListener class resides ?

Comment: What is the output of (from memory) `jar -tvf test.jar` (and the same for the other Jar)?

Comment: I personally would just use Eclipse and export as an executable JAR, but that's not as smart I guess as you don't see the details.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: It is sample app in dev environment and hence I have not put anything in package expect for GSON(as it comes).

Comment: @Sanjeev : It must belong to swing library.

Comment: @user3388324 There is no such class in Swing Library. I think you need a jar that provides ExitListener function to your App

Comment: What do you mean by `I created a jar gson.jar`?

Comment: @user3388324 How did you compile your `App` Class?

Comment: @Sanjeev: javac App.java

Comment: @user3388324 did it compile without any errors regarding ExitListener class?

Comment: @Sanjeev: Yes. And I believe ExitListener belongs to SwingUtils

Comment: @user3388324 let me ask you, from where you are using `SwingUtils` class ?

Comment: @Sanjeev I'm new to swing development. I have imported import javax.swing.*; and have called new ExitListener() and it works fine. I haven't explicitly written anything for ExitListener and hence it has to be imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either Add the jar that has `ExitListener` class in it in your class-path

```
Class-Path: test.jar gson.jar <exitlistenerjar>
```

or Write your own `ExitListener` and use in your App.

**EDIT**

On other thought you can use this code and add it to your application

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class ExitListener extends WindowAdapter {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*; are my headers and addWindowListener(new ExitListener()); is the code. I assume ExitListener is in the default package.

Comment: ExitListener does not fall under any of those imports as Java AWT/Swing does not provide ExitListener class

Comment: @user3388324 can you please provide fully qualified name for ExitListener i.e. with package structure

Comment: It might be from java.util.

Comment: Java does not provide any ExitListener. You need to download the jar that has this class. Kindly search for it on Google and add the specified jar to the classpath

Comment: Well, It was a old project. ExitListener was a public class and hence run without an issue when run using java App. Now I have added it to the manifest. Thanks.

Comment: This is exactly what I have used. Thanks